# Há algum problema em usar atributos do HTML 5 em vez de jQuery ou JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Há algum problema de segurança ou algo do tipo em usar apenas atributos, como `required` em `input`s, entre outros, em vez de jQuery?

Ou é apenas opção de alguns usar jQuery para personalizar a mensagem apenas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tecnicamente, nenhum problema. Principalmente em relação a segurança.

Com isso quero dizer que ambas as validações são feitas no navegador do usuário e **não** representam segurança em nenhum nível para o sistema, a não ser um lembrete para o usuário não esquecer os campos.

Do ponto de vista de segurança, usar ambas as técnicas é o mesmo que usar nenhuma, pois um usuário malicioso pode facilmente forjar uma requisição para o servidor.

**Sempre** execute a validação no servidor e sanitize os dados para que seu sistema não seja infectado, por exemplo, por injeção de SQL, injeção de tags `<script>` e assim por diante.

A razão de usar um código personalizado com jQuery ou JavaScript é a flexibilidade, como você mesmo menciona na pergunta, além de manter uma experiência consistente entre os diversos navegadores.